# How do function arguments within $.getJSON work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, getjson

Are there official documents explaining how the function arguments work?

```
$.getJSON("files/golfClubs.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#filtermenu").append("<option value='" + data[0].GolfCourses[index].GolfCourseID + "'>" + data[0].GolfCourses[index].GolfCourseName + "    </option>");
    });
});
```

Say for example:

```
$.getJSON("files/golfClubs.json", function (data) {
    alert(data);
//Returns undefined. Unless .JSON.stringify-ed().
});
```

Question 1: I am wondering how arguments basically pass data when you reference the same argument variable. Especially with nested jSON. What happens when you pass 2 arguments instead of one?

Question 2: In tandem with the arguments in the functions, with the JSON below, how do you access GolfCourses.GolfCourseBookings.DayBookings?

```
[
    {
        "GolfClubID": "TROPICANA",
        "GolfClubName": "Tropicana Golf and Country Club",
        "GolfCourses": [
            {
                "GolfCourseID": "1",
                "GolfCourseName": "West Course - 1st 9",
                "GolfCourseBookings": [
                    {
                        "DayNumber": 1,
                        "DayDate": "19/03/2014",
                        "DayBookings": [
                            {
                                "TimeSlotID": "0",
                                "Time" : "07:00",
                                "Class": "Closed"
                            },
                            {
                                "TimeSlotID": "1",
                                "Time" : "07:10",
                                "Class": "Closed"
                            },
                            {
                                "TimeSlotID": "2",
                                "Time" : "07:20",
                                "Class": "Closed"
                            },
```

Comment: you data is nested array object, so you can access the data like, alert(data[0])

Comment: `value[0].GolfCourses[index].GolfCourseID` not `data[0].......`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

What you have there is an array of objects (data), you can tell this because in javascript:

[] = array,
{} = object

For example:

```
var GolfCourses = []; // Array
var GolfCourses = new Array(); // Array

var GolfCourse = {}; // Object
var GolfCourse = new Object(); // Object
```

So to answers your questions:

Q1. $.getJSON retuns everything inside "data". So if you want to send 2 parameters from your server, e.g. name = "John" and last_name = "Travolta" you send it in javascript object notation (JSON):

```
data = { "name": "John", "last_name": "Travolta" };
```

And on the client side you access it like this:

```
data.name; // John
data.last_name; // Travolta
```

If you want your server to send various objects:

```
data = [
    { "name": "John",
      "last_name": "Travolta" },
    { "name": "James",
      "last_name": "Dean" }
];
```

And you access:

```
data[1].last_name; // Dean
```

Q2. Basically:

```
data[0].GolfCourses[0].GolfCouseBookings[0].DayBookings[0].Class; // Closed
```

Google "JSON or Javascript Object Notation" for info.